# highlighting math

Tags: soul, colorbox

The issue of breakable highlighting was addressed in [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex)

But how, in `latex`, do I highlight text involving `math`, something like

[image]

which, right now, I do with a succession of `\texthl` and `\colorbox`.

Comment: have a look at the `empheq` package

Comment: @JPi I took a (admittedly quick) look but I did not see anything like the above. Did I miss it?

Comment: Does [How to “highlight” text/formulas with tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formulas-with-tikz) answer your question?

Comment: Seems to; that's way more elaborate than my more direct answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is this what you intended?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}
For inline math, one can simply do \hl{colored $a=b$ math}.  For display math, the following works:
\begin{equation}
\mathcolorbox{red}{y=\frac{x^2}{q}}+z
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

[** EDIT **]

Ok, see `\hlfancy` below

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\newcommand{\hlfancy}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\begin{document}
For inline math, one can simply do \hl{colored $a=b$ math}.  For display math, the following works:
\begin{equation}
\mathcolorbox{red}{y=\frac{x^2}{q}}+z
\end{equation}  
And for the fancy version: \hlfancy{orange}{colored $a=b$ math}.  Now, \hlfancy{green}{colored $a=b$ math}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to change the color used in the `\hl` command provided by the `soul` package then you can use e.g. `\sethlcolor{green}` but note the fragility issues mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260566/how-to-reliably-switch-the-highlighting-color-with-soul

Comment: This is what I intended. Well, almost. :-))   What I _really_ would like is, instead of setting the color in the _preamble_ which would force me to define one command per color, to define a command  for `\hl` in which the color is an _option_, namely something like `inlinecolorbox{<color>}{<text with math>}`  As for creating a _robust_ command, that's even more beyond me . By the way,  the reason `\hl` had not worked for me is that instead of using `$  $` to delimit math, I was using `\(    \)` which soul does not seem to recognize.

Comment: ok, see second version.

Comment: `\hlfancy` works like magic. I wish I could take the time to understand LaTeX instead of sponging. Well, thanks very much for your patience.

Comment: You may want to look at the todonotes package for other functionality you might like.

Comment: I have and I regret having done so because I cannot afford to spend anymore time on what it offers, as good as it is: I really have to get back to writing the actual _text_.  But, when I am done, I will study it for the fourth edition! So, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: An oddity: even though `$\mathcolorbox{red}{x^{2}}$` works, `\colorbox` cannot be replaced by `\mathcolorbox` in `$f(x)=\underset{\text{\textbf{code}}}{\underbrace{\colorbox{red}{$x^{2}$}}}$'

Comment: remove the $ signs around x^{2}.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\colorbox`  instead of `\mathcolorbox`.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here is an equation:
\begin{equation}
  \colorbox{yellow}{$E = mc^2$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the `\colorbox` command is used to highlight the equation with a yellow background. The equation is enclosed in `$` symbols to put it in math mode, which is required for equations. You can replace yellow with any other color that you prefer.