# How to raise/lower table of content?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, widows-orphans

In my Table of Contents, the line for the last section of Chapter 3 is orphaned on top of the next page. I was hoping that raising the table of content a bit may bring that last line back to the bottom of the first page of the table of content.

`\vspace{-5mm}` just before `\tableofcontents` had no effect. (I didn't really expect it would.)

Is there a "simple" way?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.toc}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Numbers}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Plain Numbers}{1}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Plain counting numbers}{1}{subsection.1.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.2}Plain decimal numbers}{2}{subsection.1.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.3}}{2}{subsection.1.1.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.4}}{3}{subsection.1.1.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Signed Numbers}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}}{3}{subsection.1.2.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}}{4}{subsection.1.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}}{5}{subsection.1.2.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Picturing Numbers}{5}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3.1}}{5}{subsection.1.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3.2}}{6}{subsection.1.3.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.4}Comparing Numbers}{6}{section.1.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.4.1}}{6}{subsection.1.4.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.4.2}}{7}{subsection.1.4.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.4.3}Signed error.}{7}{subsection.1.4.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.4.4}Bounds.}{8}{subsection.1.4.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.5}Qualitative Sizes}{9}{section.1.5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.5.1}}{9}{subsection.1.5.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.5.2}Qualitative rulers}{9}{subsection.1.5.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.5.3}}{10}{subsection.1.5.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.5.4}}{10}{subsection.1.5.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.5.5}A good rule of thumb}{10}{subsection.1.5.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.6}Computing with Qualitative Sizes}{11}{section.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.6.1}}{11}{subsection.1.6.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.6.2}The reciprocal}{11}{subsection.1.6.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.6.3}}{12}{subsection.1.6.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.6.4}}{12}{subsection.1.6.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.7}Infinity}{13}{section.1.7}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.8}Neighborhoods}{14}{section.1.8}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.1}}{14}{subsection.1.8.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.2}}{15}{subsection.1.8.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.3}Neighborhood of $0$.}{15}{subsection.1.8.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.4}\DEX [side]{Sides} of a \DEX [neighborhood]{neighborhood} of a \DEX [given number]{given number}.}{15}{subsection.1.8.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.5}Neighborhood of Infinity.}{16}{subsection.1.8.5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.6}\DEX [side]{Sides} of a \DEX [neighborhood]{neighborhood} of infinity.}{17}{subsection.1.8.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.8.7}}{18}{subsection.1.8.7}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Functions}{21}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Relations}{21}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}}{22}{subsection.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}}{22}{subsection.2.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.3}}{23}{subsection.2.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Graphing Input-Output Pairs}{23}{section.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}}{23}{subsection.2.2.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.2}}{23}{subsection.2.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.3}}{25}{subsection.2.2.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.4}}{26}{subsection.2.2.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}Functions}{26}{section.2.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3.1}}{26}{subsection.2.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3.2}}{27}{subsection.2.3.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3.3}}{27}{subsection.2.3.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3.4}}{28}{subsection.2.3.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.4}Functions Defined By A Global Graph}{29}{section.2.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.4.1}}{29}{subsection.2.4.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.4.2}}{30}{subsection.2.4.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.4.3}}{31}{subsection.2.4.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.5}Offscreen Graph}{32}{section.2.5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.1}}{32}{subsection.2.5.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.2}Compactification}{33}{subsection.2.5.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.3}Magellan Inputs}{35}{subsection.2.5.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.4}Magellan outputs}{35}{subsection.2.5.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.5}Poles and Zeroes.}{35}{subsection.2.5.5}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.6}Parity of poles and zeros.}{37}{subsection.2.5.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.5.7}Conclusive information}{37}{subsection.2.5.7}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.6}Functions Defined By A Global I-O Rule}{41}{section.2.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6.1}}{41}{subsection.2.6.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6.2}}{42}{subsection.2.6.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6.3}}{43}{subsection.2.6.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6.4}}{43}{subsection.2.6.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.6.5}}{43}{subsection.2.6.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.7}Joining Plot Points Smoothly}{44}{section.2.7}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.7.1}Near-sightedness}{45}{subsection.2.7.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.7.2}Questions}{45}{subsection.2.7.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.7.3}}{47}{subsection.2.7.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.7.4}}{48}{subsection.2.7.4}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Local Analysis}{49}{chapter.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}``Thickening the plot''}{50}{section.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.1}}{50}{subsection.3.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.2}}{50}{subsection.3.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.3}}{52}{subsection.3.1.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.4}}{52}{subsection.3.1.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.5}}{52}{subsection.3.1.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}Local Graph Place}{53}{section.3.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}}{53}{subsection.3.2.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.3}Local Graph}{55}{section.3.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3.1}\DEX [local graph]{Local graph} \DEX [near]{near} $x_{0}$}{56}{subsection.3.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3.2}\DEX [local graph]{Local graph} \DEX [near]{near} $\infty $}{57}{subsection.3.3.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.4}Continuity At A Given Input}{58}{section.3.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4.1}Continuity at $\bm {x_{0}}$.}{59}{subsection.3.4.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4.2}Discontinuity at $x_{0}$.}{59}{subsection.3.4.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4.3}Quasi-continuity at $\bm {x_{0}}$.}{62}{subsection.3.4.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4.4}Magellan continuity at $\bm {x_{0}}$.}{62}{subsection.3.4.4}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.4.5}Magellan continuity at $\bm {\infty }$.}{63}{subsection.3.4.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.5}Local Code}{64}{section.3.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.6}Local Height}{66}{section.3.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.6.1}}{66}{subsection.3.6.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.6.2}}{67}{subsection.3.6.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.6.3}}{69}{subsection.3.6.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.7}Local Extreme-Height Inputs}{69}{section.3.7}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.7.1}}{69}{subsection.3.7.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.7.2}}{70}{subsection.3.7.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.7.3}}{71}{subsection.3.7.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.7.4}}{71}{subsection.3.7.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.8}Local Slope}{72}{section.3.8}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.8.1}}{72}{subsection.3.8.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.8.2}}{73}{subsection.3.8.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.9}Local Concavity}{74}{section.3.9}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.9.1}}{74}{subsection.3.9.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.9.2}}{75}{subsection.3.9.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.10}Smoothness At A Given Input}{75}{section.3.10}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.10.1}}{75}{subsection.3.10.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.10.2}}{76}{subsection.3.10.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.10.3}}{76}{subsection.3.10.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Global Analysis}{77}{chapter.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}Interpolation}{78}{section.4.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}Interpolating Bounded Local Graphs}{84}{section.4.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Interpolating the Offscreen Graph}{84}{section.4.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.3.1}}{84}{subsection.4.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.3.2}}{85}{subsection.4.3.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.4}Feature Sign-Change Inputs}{87}{section.4.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.5}Essential Feature Sign-Changes Inputs}{88}{section.4.5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.6}Essential Extreme-Height Inputs}{92}{section.4.6}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.7}Non-essential Features}{93}{section.4.7}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.8}Essential Onscreen Graph}{95}{section.4.8}
\renewcommand \chaptername {\appendixname }
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}Localization}{101}{appendix.A}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {B}Reverse Problems}{103}{appendix.B}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {C}Addition Formulas}{105}{appendix.C}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {C.1}Dimension \oldopenparen n=2\oldcloseparen : $(x_{0}+h)^{2}$ (Squares)}{105}{section.C.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {D}Polynomial Divisions}{107}{appendix.D}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {D.1}Division in Descending Exponents}{107}{section.D.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {E}List of Definitions}{109}{appendix.E}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {F}List of Theorems}{111}{appendix.F}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {G}List of How To's}{113}{appendix.G}
\contentsline {chapter}{GNU Free Documentation License}{115}{appendix*.239}
\contentsline {section}{1. Applicability And Definitions}{116}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{2. Verbatim Copying}{117}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{3. Copying In Quantity}{117}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{4. Modificatons}{118}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{5. Combining Documents}{120}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{6. Collections Of Documents}{120}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{7. Aggregation With Independent Works}{120}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{8. Translation}{121}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{9. Termination}{121}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{10. Future Revisions Of This License}{121}{section*.240}
\contentsline {section}{ADDENDUM: How to use this License for your documents}{122}{section*.240}
\contentsline {chapter}{Index}{123}{section*.241}
\contentsfinish 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe-preamble.sty}

%Begin ======================== PACKAGES =========================

\usepackage{lmodern}        %See below
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        %See below
%           \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Attempt at using Unicode symbols
%               \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\dash}
%               \DeclareRobustCommand\dash{\dash}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}  
%The following are being used for sure:     
        \definecolor{palepink}{rgb}{0.98, 0.85, 0.87}
        \definecolor{blizzardblue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.9, 0.93}
        \definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.990}%gray is pre-defined; 1 is white
        \definecolor{DarkGray}{gray}{0.85}%gray is pre-defined; 1 is white
        \colorlet{LightBlue}{blue!3!white}%number is percentage first color; second color for the rest
        \colorlet{DarkBlue}{blue!20!white}%second color for the rest
        \colorlet{link}{red!50!black}%to match the color of hyperref links

        \definecolor{magenta}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 1.0}
        \definecolor{tangerine}{rgb}{0.95, 0.52, 0.0}
        \definecolor{ufogreen}{rgb}{0.24, 0.82, 0.44}
        \definecolor{platinum}{rgb}{0.9, 0.89, 0.89}
        \definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}        
        \definecolor{atomictangerine}{rgb}{1.0, 0.6, 0.4}
        \definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}      
        \definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}
        \definecolor{lavendermagenta}{rgb}{0.93, 0.51, 0.93}        
        \definecolor{lavenderrose}{rgb}{0.98, 0.63, 0.89}
        \definecolor{MiddleBlue}{rgb}{0.67, 0.9, 0.93}      
        \definecolor{cream}{rgb}{1.0, 0.99, 0.82}
        \definecolor{brightgreen}{rgb}{0.4, 1.0, 0.0}
        \definecolor{lime(colorwheel)}{rgb}{0.75, 1.0, 0.0} 
        \definecolor{lime(web)(x11green)}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 0.0}
        \definecolor{mediumspringgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.98, 0.6}
        \definecolor{mintgreen}{rgb}{0.6, 1.0, 0.6}
        \definecolor{neongreen}{rgb}{0.22, 0.88, 0.08}
        \definecolor{springgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 0.5}
        \definecolor{sgreen}{rgb}{0.03, 0.47, 0.19}%0.0, 0.42, 0.24

%\usepackage{xparse}% is called by tcolorbox, used by Hupfer and Andrew 

    \usepackage{graphicx}   
    \usepackage{nextpage}%conflicts with epigraph (both are Wilson packages)
        \let\cleartoevenpage\relax %to avoid conflict between nextpage and epigraph
    \usepackage{epigraph} %conflicts with nextpage (both are Wilson packages)   
    \usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
        \pagestyle{scrheadings}%As per StackExchange but puts headers in italics.
%===============AMS
    \usepackage{amsmath}    
%       \renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}%Also reformatted with titlesec:
%   \usepackage{titlesec}
%       \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\arabic{subsection}.}{1em}{}{}
%    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
    \usepackage{amssymb}    
    \usepackage{amscd}  
    \usepackage{mathtools}  %fixes various deficiencies of amsmath
%===============Other Fonts
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}   %must be loaded AFTER amssymb
    \usepackage{sansmath}   %must be loaded AFTER amssymb
%===============Tools for Fonts
    \usepackage{pifont}     %used?
    \usepackage{cancel}     
    \usepackage{relsize}        %Set the font size relative to the current font size    
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %Used for underlining but also replaces italics with underlining in \em-phasized text. [normalem] restores the normal \emph
    \usepackage{bm}         %makes any maths sin?gle sym?bol or ex?pres?sion bold.
    \usepackage{maybemath}  %for math in section titles.
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}       %fancy verbatim

 %Begin breakable ColorBoxes. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318991/highlighting-math
    \usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\newcommand{\hlfancy}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}
%End breakable ColorBoxes. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318991/highlighting-math

    \usepackage{stackengine}    %For stacking symbols
    \usepackage{scalerel}
        \def\dclesize{\ThisStyle{\scalebox{1.3}{$\SavedStyle\bigcirc$}}}
        \def\dcle{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[-1pt]{\leqq}{\dclesize}}}
        \def\cle{\def\stacktype{L}\mathbin{\scalerel*{\dcle}{\dclesize}}}
%   \usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]%This is to allow math in section headers. As per stackexchange.
%===============Tools for Layout
    \usepackage{boxedminipage}%Perhaps to be replaced by tcolorbox
%===============Tools for Math
%   \usepackage[all]{xy}    %For drawing diagrams; causes error \object already defined elsewhere.
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}    %Creates commutative diagrams with TikZ
    \usepackage{polynomial} %To write polynomials
    \usepackage{polynom}        %Polynomial Division   
    \usepackage{calculator}
%===============Lists   
    \usepackage{enumerate}  
    \usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
%       [neveradjust]%standard indentation used in all cases. Overwide labels will extend into the left margin
%       %[alwaysadjust]%ensures that the lefy margin is always at least as wide as the default setting
%===============Tables  
    \usepackage{array}      
    \usepackage{booktabs}   
    \usepackage{dcolumn}        
        \newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
        \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
%   \usepackage{colortbl}%Automatically loaded by the option ``table'' in xcolor.       
    \usepackage{multirow}       
    \usepackage{hhline}         
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{spreadtab}%Can this spreadsheet be moved down to Tables?
%Begin=================================Tools for Ancillaries====================
    \usepackage{trace}      %Required by AssessmentDocumentMaker
    \usepackage{arrayjobx}      %This the version corrected by Sharpe
        \newcounter{numjob} %Allows arrayjobx to use \finkbase for the CheckableItems
    \usepackage{probsoln}       %Powers all ancillaires         
    \usepackage{ifthen}         %required by probsoln       
    \usepackage{xkeyval}        %required by probsoln       
    \usepackage{calc}           
    \usepackage{forloop}        
    \usepackage{datetime}       %required by probsoln
    \usepackage[abspath,parent]{currfile}   % abspath was the one being used before 
%End===================================Tools for Ancillaries=================== 
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}%a suggestion of the console which says that a better solution would be to use typearea



\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}

\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{, \thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}}%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs  \hspace{10mm}

    \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

%=======Begin tcolorbox ---The PACKAGE must be here. The tcolorboxes must be defined after cleveref.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% 
    \tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
        skins,%
        raster,%
        breakable,%
        xparse,%
            }%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
%=======End tcolorbox---The PACKAGE must be here. The tcolorboxes must be defined after cleveref.


%=========== Begin Tools for References============ Begin Tools for References==============        
%=========== Begin Tools for References============ Begin Tools for References==============        
%=========== Begin Tools for References============ Begin Tools for References==============        

    \usepackage{makeidx} %The \imakeindex does not work
        \makeindex
%   showidx must NOT be loaded because it is Hyperref that loads it in the Oberdiek hack below

%HOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHO  Begin HYPERREF
%HOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHOHO  Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%QDHQDHQDH  Begin the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%QDHQDHQDH  End the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx

%   \usepackage[plain]{fancyref}    %
    \hypersetup{%begin colors
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={red!50!black},
                   citecolor={blue!50!black},
                  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
                }%end colors
%==============Begin To reference footnotes             


%========Begin Hupfer to use jobname in labels BAD IDEA to be deprecated
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\currentjobname{\jobname}% 
\xpretocmd{\include}{\def\currentjobname{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
%========End Hupfer to use jobname in labels BAD IDEA to be deprecated

%==========Begin cleveref
\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
    \newcommand{\titleref}{\nameref}%displays TITLE of refered item

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs
%==========End cleveref


\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)

%======================================
%This controls the spaces before/after displaymath also used for align* Needed for CENTER
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro \normalsize%
    {%
        \setlength\abovedisplayskip{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
        \setlength\belowdisplayskip{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
    }%
\makeatother
%======================================

%===================================
%======================================

%begin----------------------------INTERITEMTEXT--Michel Bovani------------------------------                    
                \makeatletter
                \newcommand{\interitemtext}[1]{%
                \begin{list}{}
                {\itemindent=0mm\labelsep=0mm
                \labelwidth=0mm\leftmargin=0mm
                \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\@totalleftmargin}}
                \item #1
                \end{list}}
                \makeatother
%end-----------------------------------------INTERITEMTEXT---------------------------------------

%begin---------------------------------Font for DENOMINATOR-----------------------------------
             \DeclareMathAlphabet{\denom}{T1}{lmss}{sbc}{n}
%end------------------------------------------ Font for DENOMINATOR-------------------------------


%The following is probably used
%Begin ====================== SET DEFAULTS ========================
                \setdefaultenum{\bfseries 1.}{\hspace*{2.pc} \bfseries a.}{\bfseries i.}{}
                    %controls asparaenum
                \setdefaultleftmargin{5mm}{6mm}{7mm}{8mm}{}{}
                    % controls indent on compactitem
%End ======================= SET DEFAULTS =========================   

%The following is probably not used in RAF but may as well stay here since it is a ``font''

\newcommand{\Omore}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{>}}
\newcommand{\Oless}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{<}}
\newcommand{\Oeq}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{=}}
\newcommand{\Oleqq}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{\leqq}}
\newcommand{\Ogeqq}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{\geqq}}
\newcommand{\Oneq}{\mathlarger{\bigcirc}\hspace{-3mm}\mathsmaller{\neq}}

%==================================================================


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssBegin PREAMBLE

\usepackage{mwe-preamble}


    \newcounter{proc}%[chapter]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
        \tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}%This load libraries for tcolorbox       
        \tcbset{breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colframe=DarkGray,colback=LightGray,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\itshape}

\nofiles
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71444/discussion-on-question-by-schremmer-how-to-raise-lower-table-of-content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `mwe-preamble` and `mwe.toc` as generated by the MWE in the question, adding

```
\afterpage{\vspace*{-20pt}}
```

and the `afterpage` package to define that command results in the last line of the toc for section 3 coming at the bottom of page 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssBegin PREAMBLE

\usepackage{mwe-preamble}
\usepackage{afterpage}
    \newcounter{proc}%[chapter]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
        \tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}%This load libraries for tcolorbox       
        \tcbset{breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colframe=DarkGray,colback=LightGray,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\itshape}

\nofiles
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\vspace*{-20pt}}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: No matter what I tried, and I suffer from a terminal case of obstinacy, I couldn't get it to work. The Contents page remained empty. On the other hand, adding `\usepackage{afterpage}` to the `preamble.sty` of the Magnum Opus and `\afterpage{\vspace*{-20pt}}` to its Text-controls/ALL.tex just before `\tableofcontents` worked instantly! So, I am very happy that you too suffer from an acute case of obstinacy.

Comment: I just realized that _you_ wrote the `afterpage` package. So, I am doubly grateful!

Answer (score 1):

The following example replicates your behaviour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum,pgffor}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy
\foreach \CHAPTER in {First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Last} {
  \chapter{\CHAPTER{} chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
  \foreach \SECTION in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
    \section{\SECTION{} section}\lipsum[11-20]
  }
}
\section{Final section}\lipsum[21-30]% This section is orphaned in the ToC

\end{document}
```

The biggest space that you could play around with would be the space between the ToC heading and the start of the ToC entries. For this, you can use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{\dimexpr\cftaftertoctitleskip-\baselineskip}
```

The above code removes a `\baselineskip` from this gap so another `\section`'s entry can fit on the page:

[image]

Here are other options to try:

- Removing the default skip inserted *above* each `\chapter` entry - `\cftbeforechapskip`, but just for the first such entry:

  ```
  \usepackage{tocloft}
  \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{\dimexpr\cftaftertoctitleskip-\cftbeforechapskip}
  ```
- Shrinking the skip before each `\chapter` entry by (say) 20%:

  ```
  \usepackage{tocloft}
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.8\cftbeforechapskip}
  ```
- Enlarging the page to accommodate for another line on it:

  ```
  \cleardoublepage
  \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}% Allow another line on this page
  \tableofcontents
  ```

  This might be more noticeable than the other suggestions.

Comment: Something was causing an error and it took me a while to figure it out: it was `\usepackage{tocloft}` itself. My set up (See my comment to Carlisle) is indeed way too complicated. (But that's all I can do.)

Comment: Here is the message: `(./ALL.ptc

./ALL.ptc:40: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.40 ...}{\numberline {2}Functions}{21}{chapter.2}
                                                  
? `

Comment: @schremmer: Are you using `minitoc` as well? If I remember correctly, `.ptc` is a file extension from `minitoc`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, that's _one_ package I am _not_ using. But I _am_ using `titletoc` as well as `titlesec`