# \hl command is underlining instead of highlighting

Tags: highlighting, soul

How can I highlight the dollar currency symbol? For some reason, the code below is underlining rather than highlighting when I try it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\hl{\$ 10} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you include the package [`color`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/color) or [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) it will highlight the text background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\hl{\$ 10}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Using `\sethlcolor` you can set the highlighting color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{green}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\hl{\$ 10} \hlgreen{\$ 10}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second Example]

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260566/how-to-reliably-switch-the-highlighting-color-with-soul#260567) for why `\DeclareRobustCommand` should be used.

[littleO's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445279/highlighting-the-dollar-currency-symbol#445282) using `xcolor`'s `\colorbox` results in a margin around the highlighted word, which might be useful in some scenarios.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{green}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\boxgreen}[1]{\colorbox{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}
This item costs \hlgreen{\$10} in a shop

This item costs \boxgreen{\$10} in a shop
\end{document}
```

[image: Example 3]

Comment: Using the `soul` package, there is a way to add more top and bottom margin, redefining the correct leaders, like with `\makeatletter\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{\setul{}{3.5ex}\let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor\SOUL@stpreamble}\makeatother`, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349124/117801). Nevertheless, I can't find how to add left and right margin to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with just the `xcolor` package and

```
\fcolorbox{<bordor color>}{<fill color>}{<text}}
```

which yields:

[image]

If you don't want a border color, use the same `<bordor color>` and `<fill color>`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\ColorBox}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=1pt%
    \fcolorbox{gray}{yellow}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\ColorBox{\$ 10} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that worked for me using the xcolor package and a colorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{yellow!100}{\$10}
\end{document}
```