# Use \hl command to highlight a subsection title

Tags: highlighting, soul

I am trying to use the `\hl` command to highlight a subsection and subsubsection title.

I have tried wrapping the commands in a `\mbox` or between parenthesis but it doesn't seem to work. They worked with the `\ref` and `\cite` commands.

This is what I tried:

```
\hl{\mbox{\subsection{Section1}}}
\hl{{\subsection{Section1}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it inside the `section` command as so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\section{\hl{Something}}
\subsection{\hl{Something}}
\subsubsection{\hl{Something}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want the color to be green instead of yellow?

Comment: @Wallflower That's a different question which already has answers, usually stemming around defining a custom macro along the lines of either https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260566/how-to-reliably-switch-the-highlighting-color-with-soul or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352956/how-to-highlight-text-with-an-arbitrary-color

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Comment: Hey Oliver. This trick didn't work for me. Is it possible that because I am using the Elsevier's `cas-dc` class file?

Comment: @WhoCares the document classes beyond the standard few are a bit of a Wild West.

Comment: I see. So, what do you suggest? It returns errors when I highlight any line includes "\"

Comment: @WhoCares best to make a small example and post it as its own question.

Comment: I followed this advice and then discovered there are [Problems with \ref and \cite when using soul for highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23307/179342).